# MysteryLinkedList Tracing code using pen and paper

Tags: c++

So, I stumbled upon this problem recently. I can't figure out what is happening in this code. I used a compiler to create and linked list and inserted the values in it to get the answer
check this code first the question is as follows what will happen to the linklist after it is passed in this function.

front -> 25 -> 40 -> 50 -> 20 -> 50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37 /

what will be its state after it the function is called

The function is given below

```
void linklink(node*& front) {
    node* curr = front;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        node* temp = curr->next;
        if (curr->data >= curr->next->data) {
            curr->next = temp->next;
            if (curr->data == temp->data) {
                curr->next = temp->next;
                delete temp;
            } else {
                temp->next = front;
                front = temp;
            }
        } else {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I am a novice, just started to learn pointers and linked lists , **Can anyone explain how we are getting this answer** (front -> 37 -> 8 -> 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> ) The more the detailed explaining the better it is gonna be for me to understand . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: Make an example program that performs the task. Run the program in the debugging tool that came with your development environment. Use the debugger to step through `linklink`. Watch carefully and take notes. Repeat until you understand the behaviour of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When `curr` has smaller data than its next, it just moves the point to the next node.
2. When `curr` has bigger data than `curr->next`, it moves the node `curr->next` to the first of the link.
3. When `curr` is same with `curr->next`, it deletes the next node.

It would work like this.

- `curr`25 -> 40 -> 50 -> 20 -> 50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (1st while)
- 25 -> `curr`40 -> 50 -> 20 -> 50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (2nd while)
- 25 -> 40 -> `curr`50 -> 20 -> 50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (3rd while)
- 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> `curr`50 -> 50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (4th while)
- 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> `curr`50 -> 10 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (5th while)
- 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> `curr`50 -> 8 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (6th while)
- 8 -> 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> `curr`50 -> 60 -> 60 -> 37  (7th while)
- 8 -> 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> 50 -> `curr`60 -> 60 -> 37  (8th while)
- 8 -> 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> 50 -> `curr`60 -> 37  (9th while)
- 37 -> 8 -> 10 -> 20 -> 25 -> 40 -> 50 -> `curr`60  (10th while)

Comment: *"I see what's the problem"* - The OP never claimed there was a problem, nor was there any indication they wanted the list sorted. They simply want to know (a) what the function is supposed to be doing, and (b) how the result list is the result of that. You'll note, btw, this code removes duplicates. That isn't by accident.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @Antel Thank you so much !